# Matlab Terminal Output

Tags: matlab, debugging

There is rather a perplexing and yet would seem simple problem I have with a matlab script I have written. Whenever I run the script on each iteration of the loop I get an output exactly like this:

```
hoi
hoi

filenameShort = 

    '001001000_Field_1.tif'

Elapsed time is 9.304627 seconds.
```

The filenameShort is a variable that I print on each iteration of a for loop to keep track of the progress of the code, and I use the tic toc function to show the elapsed time. However what I cannot understand is why the terminal prints 'hoi hoi', I have searched my code for hoi but it does not exist. I have also researched online, and I am very confused about this.

Thanks

Comment: You need to post your code, otherwise it's impossible to tell what's going on...

Comment: use debug mode. run your script line by line till you see the `hoi hoi` printed to the screen. Then try and understand the specific command that ussued this output.

Comment: Using the debug I have identified the culprit, it is the bernsen function, which is available on the file exchange:http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40856-bernsen-local-image-thresholding/content/bernsen/bernsen.m   I am still not quite sure why it prints hoi though

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the answer in a file called, vanherk.m in the Bernsen function a fairly innocuous looking disp('hoi') line. Thanks –